# cmake protobuf_generate_cpp not invoking protoc

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, protocol-buffers

I had this working a bit ago & now updated to the latest cmake version and I'm running into issues generating source from proto files. Here's the log & minimal repro case.  Initially I had `protobuf_generate_cpp` working but for the life of me I'm not seeing the issue here.  I tried using protobuf_generate & that at least tries to invoke protoc but can't find it despite the CMake step finding protoc so I'm at a loss.  Any help would be appreciated.  If it's easier to generate the proto source files manually I guess I'll go that route.

`CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19.1)
project (vmc2c)

set ( Protobuf_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON )
set(protobuf_MODULE_COMPATIBLE ON CACHE BOOL "")

include(${PROTOBUF_ROOT}/lib/cmake/protobuf/protobuf-config.cmake)
include(${PROTOBUF_ROOT}/lib/cmake/protobuf/protobuf-module.cmake)
include(${PROTOBUF_ROOT}/lib/cmake/protobuf/protobuf-options.cmake)
include(${PROTOBUF_ROOT}/lib/cmake/protobuf/protobuf-targets.cmake)

find_package( Protobuf REQUIRED HINTS ${PROTOBUF_ROOT}/lib/cmake/protobuf )
if ( Protobuf_FOUND )
  message( STATUS "Protobuf version : ${Protobuf_VERSION}" )
  message( STATUS "Protobuf include path : ${Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIRS}" )
  message( STATUS "Protobuf libraries : ${Protobuf_LIBRARIES}" )
  message( STATUS "Protobuf compiler libraries : ${Protobuf_PROTOC_LIBRARIES}")
  message( STATUS "Protobuf lite libraries : ${Protobuf_LITE_LIBRARIES}")
  message( STATUS "Protobuf protoc : ${Protobuf_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE}")
else()
  message( WARNING "Protobuf package not found -> specify search path via PROTOBUF_ROOT variable")
endif()
  
include_directories(${Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static")

# This wasn't working, doesn't even try to run protoc
#protobuf_generate_cpp(SRCS HDRS protos/foo.proto)
add_executable(dc_server src/server.cpp ${SRCS} ${HDRS})

target_link_libraries(dc_server
  ${Protobuf_LIBRARIES}
)
protobuf_generate(
 LANGUAGE cpp
 TARGET dc_server
 PROTOS protos/foo.proto)
```

```
user@user-nuc:~/sandbox/demo_v1/vmc2c/bld$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.25.3

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
user@user-nuc:~/sandbox/demo_v1/vmc2c/bld$ rm * -rf
user@user-nuc:~/sandbox/demo_v1/vmc2c/bld$ cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DPROTOBUF_ROOT=/home/user/sandbox/protobuf/bld/install/ -Dabsl_DIR=/home/user/sandbox/protobuf/bld/install/lib/cmake/absl/ -Dutf8_range_DIR=/home/user/sandbox/protobuf/bld/install/lib/cmake/utf8_range/
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found version "1.2.11") 
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found Protobuf: /home/user/sandbox/protobuf/bld/install/bin/protoc-22.2.0 (found version "22.2.0") 
-- Protobuf version : 22.2.0
-- Protobuf include path : /home/user/sandbox/protobuf/bld/install/include
-- Protobuf libraries : /home/user/sandbox/protobuf/bld/install/lib/libprotobuf.a
-- Protobuf compiler libraries : /home/user/sandbox/protobuf/bld/install/lib/libprotoc.a
-- Protobuf lite libraries : /home/user/sandbox/protobuf/bld/install/lib/libprotobuf-lite.a
-- Protobuf protoc : /home/user/sandbox/protobuf/bld/install/bin/protoc-22.2.0
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/sandbox/demo_v1/vmc2c/bld
user@user-nuc:~/sandbox/demo_v1/vmc2c/bld$ make
[ 25%] Running cpp protocol buffer compiler on protos/foo.proto
make[2]: cpp_out: Command not found
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dc_server.dir/src/server.cpp.o
/home/user/sandbox/demo_v1/vmc2c/src/server.cpp:15:10: fatal error: foo.pb.h: No such file or directory
 #include "foo.pb.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/dc_server.dir/build.make:82: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/dc_server.dir/src/server.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/dc_server.dir/src/server.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:82: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/dc_server.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/dc_server.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:90: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: `protobuf_generate_cpp()` is commented out. it is excluded from the configuring step.

Comment: That was a note to myself & I went the direction of trying to use `protobuf_generate` which wasn't working either.  It's my understanding that `protobuf_generate` should do the same thing, which based on my log doesn't look like it can find protoc despite the cmake step saying it found one.